# Ignoring certain input

Tags: windows, input, mouse

so I want to have my system ignoring a certain type of input, namely the scroolwheel (down), if it has been triggered twice within a ratio of 0.5 seconds. Is there a way to do that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: A low-level mouse hook can both observe and filter out input.

Comment: I am really not sure how to code a mouse hook in the desired way.  If anyone here could give me a hint on which commands to use or really just the thing itself, that would be greatly appreciated. From what I have seen it does not seem very easy to get into this stuff.